# ruby server - issue doing if then else checks on imcoming data from client

Tags: ruby, server, client, message

Here is my code (and below it is my issue):

```
require "socket"

server = TCPServer.open("localhost", 2000)

loop {  
  thread.start(server.accept) do |nodervcr|
    msg = nodervcr.gets
    puts(msg)  
    if msg = "codeword"
      puts("codeword!")
    else
      puts("not codeword")
   # Note this part works: it sends the server a message and it displays it
   # You would think a simple if then else statement could redirect it according to the imcoming message from the client; which is my issue.
  end
}
```

So I tried:

```
if msg == code
  # then do this
elsif msg == code2 
  # then do this
# etc
```

But it's not working.
I've tried replacing `msg` with `nodervcr`, still nothing.
The strange part is that it's obviously getting the message, and msg does = what the client sends.. but it acts as if that variable dies immediately. I'm new to ruby. please help thanks.

Comment: ( the client sends the server a message, not the server lol ) so to clarify the server gets the messages and displays them. I just want to be able to call 'functions' based on the incoming messages  (or is it methods they call them in ruby? ) ( if msg = this then do this if msg = that then to that etc.

Comment: please add the conditonal call you're using into the code, and what you mean "the variable dies immediately" - can you also show where you are trying to access the variable?

Comment: ok for example in the loop. if msg = "codeword" then function_name. that should call the method or function or w/e they refer to it as ( the label in batch they call it )  - problem is it doesn't. putting the conditions on the next line below the if statement does nothing either. so that's what i mean by the variable seems to die immediately. it doesn't recognize it.  i can send the code word to the server and it just ignores it like it never happened.

Comment: require "socket"

server= TCPServer.open("localhost", 2000)

loop {

thread.start(server.accept) do | nodervcr |

msg = nodervcr.gets

puts(msg)

if msg = "codeword"
puts("codeword!")
else
puts(" not codeword! ")



end }

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems in your code. But the main problem is that when you use something like Telnet, you probally are giving a enter.

So your sending "codeword" + CRLF (codeword\r\n). Thats not the same as your check: msg == "codeword"

What you should do is strip the input from these chars (strip). It removes the CRLF and it then works

Remember. Variable Assignments are = (single) comparing is double ==

Below the working code:

```
require "socket"

server = TCPServer.open("127.0.0.1", 2000)

loop {  
  Thread.start(server.accept) do |nodervcr| # Thread, not thread
    msg = nodervcr.gets
    # puts(msg)  
    p  msg # use this so see all the invisiable chars
    if msg.strip == "codeword" # stip the input
      puts("codeword!")
    else
      puts("not codeword")
    end
   # Note this part works: it sends the server a message and it displays it
   # You would think a simple if then else statement could redirect it according to the imcoming message from the client; which is my issue.
  end
}
```